# Viewing DWFX in Forge - Properties

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have tried couple of methods loading a DWF model in Forge viewer (v7):

- using Autodesk.DWF
- translating using Derivative APIs

With both methods, the whole properties are combined together into one single Tab, although the initial model has separate tabs for item properties.
When I open the DWF file in Navisworks I can see those tabs.

I have also noticed when I downloaded the parts (after translating) the properties.db is 0kb but there is a section_properties.db file which has the data. the 'category' field (_objects_Attr table) for item properties is empty (except for internal Forge fields that start and with __)

Is there any way to preserve the tabs (categories) when translating the model?

Thanks,
Afshin

**EDIT 1:**

This is the image from Forge viewer, there is no category:
[image]

This is from original dwf file, same item selected, with properties id different tabs:
[image]

Comment: can you please add a screen capture with details? the property panel should have categories, but not separate panels...

Comment: Hi @AugustoGoncalves, edited the question with screenshots form Forge and Navisworks. same item selected in both views.

Comment: Viewer has 1 tab, but group properties into groups. Would you be able to share a sample DWF model so we can investigate/confirm? I suspect that's just how the DWF was created... you can use forge.help[at]autodesk.com

Comment: Those groups are from properties that are same name but from different tabs, the rest of the properties from all other tabs are ungrouped. I have sent this file to that address about on 15th of June (request number 12456). appreciate any help

Comment: Hey man, sorry for the late reply. I updated the thread on forge.help. if you translate the model loaded in Navis (nwd) you'll be able to obtain the required configuration.